# How to add shipping method in magento

Tags: magento-1.7, magento-1.9, magento-1.8, shipping

How to change shipping rate in magento when check out.
i have many tried to make

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Module_CustomShippingrate>
            <module>0.0.1</module>
        </Module_CustomShippingrate>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <module_customshippingrate>
                <class>Module_CustomShippingrate_Model</class>
            </module_customshippingrate>
        </models>
    </global>
    <!-- Default configuration -->
    <default>
        <carriers>
            <module_customshippingrate>
                <active>1</active>
                <model>module_customshippingrate/carrier</model>
                <title>Shipping Rate</title>
                <sort_order>10</sort_order>
                <sallowspecific>0</sallowspecific>
            </module_customshippingrate>
        </carriers>
    </default>
</config>
```

**Call Of Shipping method class**

```
public function collectRates(Mage_Shipping_Model_Rate_Request $request) {
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need lot of work  for create custom shipping method:

**Missing  system.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
   <sections>
    <carriers>
        <groups>
            <newmodule translate="label" module="shipping">
                <label>Carrier Name</label>
                <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                <sort_order>13</sort_order>
                <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                   <fields>
                      <account translate="label">
                            <label>Account number</label>
                            <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                            <sort_order>7</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                        </account>
                        <active translate="label">
                            <label>Enabled</label>
                            <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>
                            <source_model>adminhtml/system_config_source_yesno</source_model>
                            <sort_order>1</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                        </active>
                        <contentdesc translate="label">
                            <label>Package Description</label>
                            <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                            <sort_order>12</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                        </contentdesc>
                        <!--
                        If the free_shipping_enable flag enable, the system will check free_shipping_subtotal to give free shipping
                        otherwise will use shopping cart price rule behaviour
                        -->
                        <free_shipping_enable translate="label">
                            <label>Free shipping with minimum order amount</label>
                            <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>
                            <source_model>adminhtml/system_config_source_enabledisable</source_model>
                            <sort_order>21</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                        </free_shipping_enable>
                        <free_shipping_subtotal translate="label">
                            <label>Minimum order amount for free shipping</label>
                            <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                            <sort_order>22</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                        </free_shipping_subtotal>
                        <dutiable translate="label">
                            <label>Shipment Dutiable</label>
                            <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>
                            <source_model>adminhtml/system_config_source_yesno</source_model>
                            <sort_order>13</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                        </dutiable>
                        <gateway_url translate="label">
                            <label>Gateway URL</label>
                            <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                            <sort_order>2</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                        </gateway_url>
                        <handling_type translate="label">
                            <label>Calculate Handling Fee</label>
                            <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>
                            <source_model>shipping/source_handlingType</source_model>
                            <sort_order>10</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>0</show_in_store>
                        </handling_type>
                        <handling_action translate="label">
                            <label>Handling Applied</label>
                            <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>
                            <source_model>shipping/source_handlingAction</source_model>
                            <sort_order>11</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>0</show_in_store>
                        </handling_action>
                        <handling_fee translate="label">
                            <label>Handling fee</label>
                            <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                            <sort_order>12</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                        </handling_fee>
                        <max_package_weight translate="label">
                            <label>Maximum Package Weight (Please consult your shipping carrier for maximum supported shipping weight)</label>
                            <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                            <sort_order>13</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                        </max_package_weight>
                        <id translate="label">
                            <label>Access ID</label>
                            <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                            <backend_model>adminhtml/system_config_backend_encrypted</backend_model>
                            <sort_order>5</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                        </id>
                        <password translate="label">
                            <label>Password</label>
                            <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                            <backend_model>adminhtml/system_config_backend_encrypted</backend_model>
                            <sort_order>6</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                        </password>
                        <shipping_intlkey translate="label">
                            <label>Shipping key (International)</label>
                            <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                            <backend_model>adminhtml/system_config_backend_encrypted</backend_model>
                            <sort_order>8</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                        </shipping_intlkey>
                        <shipping_key translate="label">
                            <label>Shipping key</label>
                            <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                            <backend_model>adminhtml/system_config_backend_encrypted</backend_model>
                            <sort_order>8</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                        </shipping_key>
                        <sort_order translate="label">
                            <label>Sort order</label>
                            <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                            <sort_order>100</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                        </sort_order>
                        <title translate="label">
                            <label>Title</label>
                            <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                            <sort_order>2</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                        </title>
                        <sallowspecific translate="label">
                            <label>Ship to applicable countries</label>
                            <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>
                            <sort_order>90</sort_order>
                            <frontend_class>shipping-applicable-country</frontend_class>
                            <source_model>adminhtml/system_config_source_shipping_allspecificcountries</source_model>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                        </sallowspecific>
                        <specificcountry translate="label">
                            <label>Ship to Specific countries</label>
                            <frontend_type>multiselect</frontend_type>
                            <sort_order>91</sort_order>
                            <source_model>adminhtml/system_config_source_country</source_model>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                        </specificcountry>
                        <showmethod translate="label">
                            <label>Show method if not applicable</label>
                            <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>
                            <sort_order>92</sort_order>
                            <source_model>adminhtml/system_config_source_yesno</source_model>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                        </showmethod>
                        <specificerrmsg translate="label">
                            <label>Displayed Error Message</label>
                            <frontend_type>textarea</frontend_type>
                            <sort_order>80</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                        </specificerrmsg>
                    </fields>
                </newmodule>
            </groups>
        </carriers>
    </sections>
</config>
```

**Shipping class is not define properly**

Every shipping method have an unique identifier in your class it missing

```
<?php

/**
* Our test shipping method module adapter
*/
class Module_CustomShippingrate_Model_Carrier extends Mage_Shipping_Model_Carrier_Abstract
{
  /**
   * unique internal shipping method identifier
   *
   * @var string [a-z0-9_]
   */
  protected $_code = 'newmodule';

  /**
   * Collect rates for this shipping method based on information in $request
   *
   * @param Mage_Shipping_Model_Rate_Request $data
   * @return Mage_Shipping_Model_Rate_Result
   */
  public function collectRates(Mage_Shipping_Model_Rate_Request $request)
  {
    // skip if not enabled
    if (!Mage::getStoreConfig('carriers/'.$this->_code.'/active')) {
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * here we are retrieving shipping rates from external service
     * or using internal logic to calculate the rate from $request
     * you can see an example in Mage_Usa_Model_Shipping_Carrier_Ups::setRequest()
     */

    // get necessary configuration values
    $handling = Mage::getStoreConfig('carriers/'.$this->_code.'/handling');

    // this object will be returned as result of this method
    // containing all the shipping rates of this method
    $result = Mage::getModel('shipping/rate_result');

    // $response is an array that we have
    foreach ($response as $rMethod) {
      // create new instance of method rate
      $method = Mage::getModel('shipping/rate_result_method');

      // record carrier information
      $method->setCarrier($this->_code);
      $method->setCarrierTitle(Mage::getStoreConfig('carriers/'.$this->_code.'/title'));

      // record method information
      $method->setMethod($rMethod['code']);
      $method->setMethodTitle($rMethod['title']);

      // rate cost is optional property to record how much it costs to vendor to ship
      $method->setCost($rMethod['amount']);

      // in our example handling is fixed amount that is added to cost
      // to receive price the customer will pay for shipping method.
      // it could be as well percentage:
      /// $method->setPrice($rMethod['amount']*$handling/100);
      $method->setPrice($rMethod['amount']+$handling);

      // add this rate to the result
      $result->append($method);
    }

    return $result;
  }

  /**
   * This method is used when viewing / listing Shipping Methods with Codes programmatically
   */
  public function getAllowedMethods() {
    return array($this->_code => $this->getConfigData('name'));
  }
}
```

See at [magento tutorial](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/shipping/create-shipping-method-module).How to create custom carrier method